# How to get Image path of an image displayed in a JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I have been creating a software in which I display images by getting their location from a MySQL database. I need to get the location of the image displayed in the `JLabel`, so when the user clicks on the label I can get image location and information related to it from the database.

Comment: Well, you have the location already when you create the JLabel. So store it somewhere at that point (in a Map<JLabel, Path> for example), and retrieve it from there when you need it.

Comment: Note that your labels should probably be buttons if you're supposed to click on it.

Comment: @JBNizet i have a single jlabel which is added  using a while loop . and i  added actionlistner to that jLabel